# Split large excel file to multiple smaller file by user defined rows through powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

Im looking to split large excel file into multiple excel file

My sample excel file

```
Name Value value2
abc1  10    100
abc2  20    200
abc3  30    300
abc4  40    400
abc5  50    500
abc6  60    600
abc7  70    700
abc8  80    800
```

Expected result

Batch1.xlsx

```
Name Value Value2
abc1 10    100
abc2 20    200
abc3 30    300
```

Batch2.xlsx

```
Name Value Value2
abc4 40    400
abc5 50    500
abc6 60    600
```

Batch3.xlsx

```
Name Value Value2
abc7 70    700
abc8 80    800
```

Myscript strucks in loops .. As a beginner looking for some assistance ..

Example: user choosing data to be splitted with 3 rows ., If have 8 rows data of input file  ., file3.xlsx can keep remaining 2 rows .

```
$nom = Read-Host 'Enter number of rows of data want to be in a file'

$nom = [int]$nom + [int]1

$nom1 = 'A'+ $nom

$nxc = 100

$meto = 'A1'



For ($nom; $nom -le $nxc) {
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.visible = $true
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.open("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\rax\Master\in.xlsx")
$worksheet = $workbook.sheets.item("Sheet1") 
$worksheet.Range("$meto","$nom1").EntireRow.copy()

$wb2=$excel.workbooks.open("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\rax\out.xlsx")
$targetRange=$wb2.Worksheets.Item('Sheet1').Range("A1").EntireRow
$wb2.Worksheets.Item('Sheet1').Activate()
$targetRange.PasteSpecial(-4163)
$meto = $wb2.Worksheets.Item('Sheet1').UsedRange.Rows.Count
$wb2.RefreshAll()
$wb2.Save() 
$workbook.Worksheets.Item('Sheet1').Activate()
$met = $workbook.Worksheets.Item('Sheet1').UsedRange.Rows.Count
$nxc = $met

$meto = [int]$meto + [int]1


$nom = [int]$meto - [int]1
$nom = [int]$nom + [int]$nom
$nom
$excel.Quit()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize an awesome module developed by [Doug finke](https://twitter.com/dfinke) . [Import-Excel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/2.4.0)

below code will solve you problem.

```
$r=@()
$t=$C=1
Import-Excel -Path C:\Temp\test.xlsx|Foreach-Object -Process {
    #Append rows in an array
    $r += $_

    #Save in a new excel when count reaches 3
    if($C -eq 3){
        $r | Export-Excel -Path C:\Temp\test_$t.xlsx

        #reset values
        $r=@()
        $c=1
       $t++
    }
    else{
        #increment row count
        $c++
    }
}

#save remaining rows
$r|Export-Excel -Path C:\Temp\test_$t.xlsx
```

You can rename variables accordingly.